# Which method is called when adding a key to a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary, python-collections

I would like to inherit the `OrderedDict` class to set up a maximum length to the dict.

I did :

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class limitedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, length):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self)
        self.length = length
```

But now I don't see which function to overwrite to catch the "adding a key" event.
I Googled for a while without finding the answer. Even special functions are not clearly an answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__

Comment: seems to be correct insight, thanks !

Comment: Note that your current `__init__` signature doesn't allow initializing the dict as `limitedDict(a=2, b=2)...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dunder method [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274532/which-method-is-called-when-adding-a-key-to-a-dict/49274998#comment85551483_49274532) by  [@AshwiniChaudhary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary). You need to distinguish overwriting and setting a new key, though.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class limitedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, length):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self)
        self.length = length

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self and len(self) >= self.length:
            raise RuntimeWarning("Dictionary has reached maximum size.")
            # Or do whatever else you want to do in that case
        else:
            OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

Note that while the `update` method also allows adding new keys, it calls `__setitem__` under the hood, as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274532/which-method-is-called-when-adding-a-key-to-a-dict/49274998#comment85555472_49274998).

If the dictionary exceeds the maximum size you might want to `self.popitem(last=False)` until it matches the length (`last=False` for FIFO order, `last=True` for LIFO order, the default).

Comment: `update` will eventually be calling `__setitem__` for items present in `other`, hence it is redundant. Secondly, `update` also works with iterables, not just dicts.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary True.